# Collect_set in db2

Tags: db2

Is there any functionality in db2 where we can add column name in collect_Set which are not required in group by.

i.e.

In hive

```
    select name,count(id),collect_set(country)[0] as country from mytable  group by name;
```

above query is working in hive. thing i want to execute in db2.But its giving below error.

```
    No authorized routine named "COLLECT_SET" of type "FUNCTION".
```

can someone plz guide me how can i handle same thing in db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly the same, but the closest thing in Db2 I'm aware of is  `LISTAGG()`.

Availability of the `LISTAGG()` is dependent on your Db2 platform and version.

```
select name,count(id),listagg(country) as country_list 
 from mytable  
 group by name;
```

Note that in Db2, `LISTAGG()` has two forms

```
LISTAGG(DISTINCT mycolumn) --duplicates removed
LISTAGG(ALL mycolumn)      --duplicates kept
```